# When I add "com.huawei.hms:hianalytics", I get ResourceException "Could not get resource". How to fix it?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

Since I started adding Huawei SDK, I am having problems with builds.

First when I added plugin "com.huawei.agconnect", I had to disable org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache.

Now I added "implementation("com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.10.0.302")" into Module:App. With it I can´t build project, it brokes other libraries. For example:

***implementation("com.github.davidmigloz:youtube-android-player-api-gradle:1.2.2.1")***

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/com/github/davidmigloz/youtube-android-player-api-gradle/1.2.2.1/youtube-android-player-api-gradle-1.2.2.1.pom'.
```

This is Project:Kts

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://developer.huawei.com/repo/") } 
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.6")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")
        classpath("com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.0.300") 
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0")
    }

}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://developer.huawei.com/repo/") } 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in Huawei library version, correct version is:

```
com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.10.0.300
```

You can check latest version [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050705116).

I also found out that there is newer version of agconnect (com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.9.1.300), which should be compatible with Gradle version 8, but build cache still not working.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I can't enable build cache either.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error, as an additional solution method to replace the `com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.10.0.302` library with the `com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.10.0.300` library, I deleted the line `android:allowBackup="true"` which is located under the activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml file  and did not encounter any errors.

Also, instead of deleting the line, `android:allowBackup="true"` can be used instead of `android:allowBackup="false"`. The line `android:allowBackup="true"` in the AndroidManifest.xml file conflicts because it is defined as `android:allowBackup="false"` in the `com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.10.0.302` library.

In addition, when the `com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.10.0.302` library is replaced with the `com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.10.0.300` library, some configurations optimized in the new version will not be available in the old version because the version was downgraded. For detailed information, you can review the [Version Change History](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050705116) page. I hope it will be useful for you.